# Camera: Focus Object shift

Tags: camera, depth-of-field

Is it possible to adjust a camera's focus when DOF is locked to an object ?
As in: shift focus forward or back relative to dof.focus_object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try parenting an empty to your focus object, set with constraints to always point towards the camera, then have a second empty parented to the first, that moves along the local axis towards or away from the camera, and set your DoF focus to that empty instead. Then you can have the DoF moving along a line from your camera to the object you want while being able to control the distance.

Comment: Neat. Now I just have to figure out how to constrain the 2nd empty to move in line between the camera and the object. Got the other bits working as you explained, but I've not really played with constrains yet so not sure how to set it up correctly.
It was more of a theoretical question though so I'm in no rush.
Thanks for the answer!